# Slim 3 - Access URI arguments from middleware

Tags: php, slim

I've got a route that contains parameters I capture into the $args variable:

```
$app->get('/v1/download/{transactionId}', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args) {   
...
```

I also use middleware on this route and I need the content of `$args` to be accessible from the middleware function.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I can only seem to access the request data but not the arguments.

Would really appreciate an assist!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is [documented here](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/request.html#route-object)

If you have access to request object, then you can get route arguments like this:

```
$route = $request->getAttribute('route');
$courseId = $route->getArgument('transactionId');
```

**Edit**: You need to enable `determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware` settings to make it works, because by default, route is resolved after all middlewares executed.

```
$app = new \Slim\App([
    'settings' => [
         ...
         // Set to true to be able to access the route from within the
         // middleware, otherwise it will return null
         'determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware' => true,
         ...
    ]
]);
```

Comment: I think you will need to enable `determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware` settings before it can work